# core-localstorage doesn't save when modifying (rather than replacing) a value

Tags: polymer

I have something like this that holds a hash of responses from core-ajax.  The idea is, if it's in cache present it right away and replace it when the ajax round trip completes successfully.

```
<core-ajax auto
           url="/some/rest/path"
           on-core-response="{{setDetail}}"
           on-core-error="{{_setDetail}}"
           handleas="json"></core-ajax>

<core-localstorage id="detail-storage" 
                   name="category-detail-storage"
                   value="{{cachedDetails}}"></core-localstorage>
```

setDetail looks like....

```
Polymer({...
...,
setDetail: function(e,detail) { 
             var response = detail.response;
             if(response != null) {
               this.cachedDetails[this.id] = response;
             }
             _setDetail(); // Which pulls from the cache
           },...})
```

The problem I'm running into, is assigning to a key in cachedDetails doesn't trigger the change event, and therefore save method in core-localstorage which leaves me digging into the shadowRoot of my element to trigger save manually, like...

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#detail-storage').save();
```

Does this seem erroneous to anyone else?   When I replace the item completely in other uses of core-localstorage it seems to work fine...

Answer (score 0):

You can put it like this:

```
<core-ajax auto
       url="/some/rest/path"
       on-core-response="{{setDetail}}"
       on-core-error="{{_setDetail}}"
       handleas="json"></core-ajax>

<core-localstorage id="detail-storage" 
      name="category-detail-storage"
      value="{{setDetail}}">
</core-localstorage>
```